# Angular Routing with multiple components in Apache

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have configured following route which takes 2 path components, works perfectly fine on local server with **base href="/"**  in index.html. I had to change **base href="/"** to **base href="./"** while deploying in production server as a result the routes are not working. What am I doing wrong here.

```
const routes : Routes =[{path:":firstPathComponant/:secondPathComponant", component: HomeComponent}]
```

.htaccess

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  IndexIgnore */*
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule (.*) index.html
```

Comment: I guess you need to search for how to enable HTML5 pushState on Apache.

Comment: It would probably better to edit your question and add the code there to preserve formatting.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I updated question to include .htaccess can you please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your application in the root directory of the domain, or in the sub-folder?

Comment: its under /public_html/somefolder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#basics-base-href):

> If the `app` folder is the application root, as it is for the sample application, set the `href` value exactly as shown here.

If your production URL is `http://domain.tld/somefolder`, you should set the `href` value to `<base href="/somefolder">`